# How can I preserve sort order?

Tags: sorting, google-play-music

Is it possible to get Google Music to preserve my selected sort order? I'm getting tired of clicking the "Artist" column header to sort by artist name every single time I switch views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked this question, Google updated it so that it now automatically preserves sort order for each playlist within a session, so this question is no longer relevant.